# Write access violation when solving sparse linear system with a large matrix

Tags: c++, memory, eigen3

Good evening, 
i've written a program that uses Eigen3 to solve a sparse linear system where the input matrix is an SPD matrix in .mtx format and the output x should be a vector of ones.
I've to test 9 different matrices, the program works fine with the first 7 matrices, while the 8th matrix causes a "write access violation" exception.
The first 7 matrices are all < 100MB of dimension, while this one is around 300MB.

This is the code:

```cpp
typedef Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<SM> CS;
typedef Eigen::VectorXd V; 
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> SM;

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SM mat;
    Eigen::loadMarket(mat, std::string(argv[1]));
    SM A = mat.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>();
    CS solver;
    V b(A.rows(), 1), x(A.rows(), 1), xe(A.rows(), 1);
    xe.setOnes(A.cols(), 1);

    b = A * xe;

    solver.compute(A); 
    x = solver.solve(b);
}
```

The crash occours on solver.compute(A).
Debugging the code i've found out that the error is inside SimplicialCholesky_impl.h

```cpp
Li[p] = k;                          /* store L(k,i) in column form of L */
```

Li is defined as follows:

```cpp
 StorageIndex* Li = m_matrix.innerIndexPtr();
```

but the value of Li is 0x0000000000000000 and i suppose this is somehow wrong, but i can't really understand what to do to solve the problem, especially because this happens only with this specific matrix.

The interested matrix is this one https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/Janna/StocF-1465.html .

I'm working with msvc and visual studio 2017, the build is release x64.

Comment: You very likely got a bad alloc because from the given statistics this matrix requires about 32 GB of memory just to store the L factor.

Comment: I'm currently using an azure vm with 64 GB of RAM, so that should not be the problem right? 
I'm able to process the matrix using both MATLAB and even Eigen + mkl (pardiso), but this is the only test that causes memory problems.

Comment: The 32GB would be for single precision. With double precision you need ~48GB (for the L-factor) plus very likely something more during the calculation. Also, I'm not sure how efficient memory-growth is implemented.

Comment: Thank you very much, so there is nothing i can do about it (except increasing memory of course)? 
If so i'll proceed to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `SparseMatrix` uses `int` to store indices and thus so does `SimplicialLDLT<SM>` for its `L` factor. For your problem, you clearly need `long int`, so all you have to do is:

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,ColMajor,long> SM;
```

but this will take time because non-supernodal Cholesky factorization are good for 2D problems only and this matrix comes from a 3D finite element discretization.

Comment: I'll try this out in these days and let you know if this works, thanks!

Comment: On my computer it took few hours, and about 60GB.

Comment: Worked as expected, took about 7 hours! Thank you very much.